# How some virus are able to reach the CNS?

Tags: immunology, brain, virology, immune-system, blood-brain-barrier

I know that the lymphocytic choriomeningitis virus (LCMV) could provoke meningitis and encephalitis when this virus reaches the brain. However, there are other viruses like Varicella (VSV), Cytomegalovirus (CMV) or Herpes (HSV) that are able to reach the brain, hence, to pass trough the blood-brain barrier (BBB) and damage the central nervous system (CNS).

1) Since the blood-brain barrier allows only the free diffusion of some molecules such as water, some gasses and lipid soluble molecule, I was wondering by which mechanism a virus is able to pass trough the BBB.

2) Since the CNS is an immuno-privileged space (where basically the immune system is down-regulated), how does the body eliminate a virus that had reached the brain?

Comment: What on god's green earth is the "SNC"?

Comment: @4DNeuron sorry is CNS, I've already edit the question

Comment: you should do some homework before posting, maybe start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_nervous_system_viral_disease and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3367119/

Answer (score -1):

some viruses like rabies get into the peripheral nerves, and travel through those to the spine , unimpeded by any obstacle.